# Custom brace initializer

Tags: c++, uniform-initialization, list-initialization

Let's say I have this struct:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int field1;
    char *field2;
    MyStruct(int a, char* b): field2(b) {
        field1 = doStuff(a);
    }
    MyStruct(int a): MyStruct(a, nullptr) {}
    ~MyStruct();
}
```

As far as I know this is not an aggregate as I have some constructors.

What I want to achieve is to use the *curly brace initializer* in a custom way, which means using a code like this:

```
MyStruct x = { 1, "string" };
```

which implicitly calls the proper constructor (the first one in this case).

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: [initializer_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)? BTW... in this particular case, you can reduce your code by using a [default argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

Comment: If you just use `const char*` instead of `char*`, it simply compiles as is. What's the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there.  `MyStruct x = { 1, "string" };` is called *copy list initialization*.  It will attempt to construct a `MyStruct` from the available constructors with the parameters supplied from the *braced-init-list*

Your issue is that your constructor takes a `char*` while `"string"` is a `const char[N]` which can decay to a `const char*`, not a `char*`.  So making thing that change

```
struct MyStruct {
    int field1;
   const char* field2;
    MyStruct(int a, const char* b): field2(b) {
        field1 = a;
    }
    MyStruct(int a): MyStruct(a, nullptr) {}
    ~MyStruct() {}
};
```

Then

```
MyStruct x = { 1, "string" };
```

Will work.  If you want to make this a little more bullet proof you can change `field2` to be a `std::string` and use

```
struct MyStruct {
    int field1;
    std::string field2;
    MyStruct(int a, const std::string& b): field1(a), field2(b) {}
    MyStruct(int a): MyStruct(a, "") {}
    ~MyStruct() {}
};
```

Comment: If you need `field2` to be changeable, you need to either use `std::string` or copy the string manually. Even if you don’t need `const`-ness, you should probably still use `std::string` or the C++17 `std::string_view`.

Comment: @DanielH nice thing the `string_view`. This is immutable so it was a `const char*`, it did not copy it as I did think it wasn't important. I was wrong! Just to be clear, if `field1` is constant too (and then I have a `const int a` in costructor, everything keep working?

Comment: You can initialize a non-`const` variable with a `const` value. The issue here is that you can’t initialize a *pointer to non-`const`* with a `pointer to *const*`, because then you could change the value through the created pointer.